# Functional equivalent of function adding two elements to a vector in a loop

Tags: rust

I am trying to write the following function in a functional way:

```rust
fn word_split(word: &String) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut split: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for (i, _) in word.chars().enumerate() {
        res.push(word[i..].to_string());
        res.push(word[..i].to_string());
    }
    splits
```

The main difficulty that I had is that there are two inserts happening in the function. I do not know how to express it in the best in a functional way. I came up with something like:

```rust
fn word_split(word: &String) -> Vec<String> {

    let word_splits1: Vec<String> = word
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(i, _)| word[i..].to_string() )
        .collect();

    let word_splits2: Vec<String> = word
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(i, _)| { word[..i].to_string() })
        .collect();

    let word_splits: Vec<String> = [word_splits1, word_splits2].concat();
    word_splits
}
```

but obviously it is much worse than initial version.

Comment: You need `char_indices()` instead of `chars().enumerate()`. The first one will yield the indices of character boundaries; the second one only counts characters and will cause the indexing to panic at the character after the first non-ASCII character in the string.

Comment: Also aside, I don't really understand this "functional" obsession. You have code that is compact, idiomatic, readable, and (if you fix the `enumerate()` issue) bug-free -- why rewrite it? Sure, you could achieve the same thing with a `flat_map` and some `chain`s or a `fold` but what would be the point? Sorry, this is not your fault, I just have some lingering frustration...

Comment: @trentcl thanks for advice with `char_indices()`. To your other point - just to see how it would look like and which of the versions would be neater.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is good, but maybe [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_at) can help you a bit.

One way to do it:

```
fn word_split2(word: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    word
        .char_indices()
        .flat_map(|(i, _ch)| {
            let (left, right) = word.split_at(i);
            vec![left, right].into_iter() // array would be better than vec!, but does not support into_iter as of now
        })
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .collect()
}
```

Your second version could be written as:

```
fn word_split2(word: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let (splits1, splits2) = word
        .char_indices()
        .map(|(i, _ch)| {
            let (left, right) = word.split_at(i);
            (left.to_string(), right.to_string())
        })
        .unzip::<_, _, Vec<_>, Vec<_>>();
    [splits1, splits2].concat()
}
```